# Change currentLocation url first folder

Tags: javascript, currentlocation

I get the current location URL with:

```
var currentLocation = window.location;
```

I always get back a value like: http://2016.test.ch/v3/index.html. The first folder (v3 in this example) is the version of the website prototype. How is it possible to access this specific first folder value inside the url and change it to something like http://2016.test.ch/v2/index.html?

Thanks for your help

Comment: look up js regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(.*\/\/[^\/]+\/)(\w+)(.*)$
```

And then replace that with:

```
$1v2$3 // {v2} could be anything else
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC1xN0/2)

---

```js
var currentLocation = 'http://2016.test.ch/v3/index.html'; // window.location
var FirstFolder = 'v2'; // or any version you want
alert(currentLocation.replace(/^(.*\/\/[^\/]+\/)(\w+)(.*)$/, '$1'+FirstFolder+'$3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the digit and `.replace` it. As simple as that.

```
var currentLocation = window.location.toString(); // avoid changes to URL in the browser
var newLocation = currentLocation.replace(/\/v(\d+)/, function(whole, num){
    return "/v" + (+num - 1);
});
```

Assuming, of course, as you yourself said:

> I always get back a value like: http://2016.test.ch/v3/index.html.

there is a `/v{digit(s)}` bit in the URL